# How to fetch the existing value of a form field in the form?

Tags: forms, files

I have a minimal form with a single field to add an image to an entity and a save button. I have used `managed_file` to add the image.

After adding the image from form the image gets saved in db.

Next time the user opens the form, it shows blank field and after adding a value current one gets replaced. What I want to do is user should see the existing value of the field when reopening the form.

How do I do this?

[Edit]:

Code for my form is:

```
// Form Definition
function custom_profile_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form = array();
  $form['picture'] = array(
    '#title' => t('File'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('The uploaded file will be processed.'),
  );

  $form['buttons']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Import'),
  );

  return $form;
}

// Form Validation
function custom_profile_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $file = file_save_upload('picture');
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  $uploaded = file_save($file);
  $upl = file_move($uploaded, "public://");
  $form_state['storage']['fid'] = $upl->fid;
}

// Form Submission
function custom_profile_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    global $user;
    $user1 = user_load($user->uid);
    $file = file_load($form_state['storage']['fid']);
    $edit = array(
      'picture' => $file,
    );
    user_save($user1, $edit);
}
```

Comment: "I have a minimal form with a single field" - can we see it?

Comment: @Mołot: Added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#default_value` attribute of the `managed_file` to show the existing value of the field.

You can get the value of `fid` from database and set value into `#default_value`.

Example:

```
$form['picture'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Image'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#description' => '',
  '#default_value' => 1, //fid from database
  '#upload_location' => 'public://image_example_images/',
);
```